# How func ContainsAny() works in Go?

Tags: go, boolean

Considering the following code

```
func main() {
        arg := os.Args
        if len(arg[1]) != 1 || len(arg) != 2 {
            fmt.Println("Give me a letter.")
            return
        }
        if (strings.IndexAny(arg[1], "yw") == 0) {
            fmt.Printf("%q is a semivowel.\n", arg[1])
        } else if strings.IndexAny(arg[1], "aeiou") == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%q is a vowel.\n", arg[1])
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%q is a consonant.\n", arg[1])
        }
}
```

and more specifically this section:

```
    if (strings.IndexAny(arg[1], "yw") == 0) {
        fmt.Printf("%q is a semivowel.\n", arg[1])
    } else if strings.IndexAny(arg[1], "aeiou") == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%q is a vowel.\n", arg[1])
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%q is a consonant.\n", arg[1])
    }
```

I could not understand why it only worked when I informed the bool equal to **zero** but not when equal to **one**. (According to the official documentation https://pkg.go.dev/strings#ContainsAny shouldn't it be equal to 1, as in true?)

Comment: You're not using ContainsAny. Also, in Go you cannot compare booleans to integers, i.e. 1 is not the same as (or even equivalent to) true.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the function you used should return an integer:

```
package strings // import "strings"

func IndexAny(s, chars string) int
    IndexAny returns the index of the first instance of any Unicode code point
    from chars in s, or -1 if no Unicode code point from chars is present in s.
```

and `strings.ContainsAny` returns a boolean

```
package strings // import "strings"

func ContainsAny(s, chars string) bool
    ContainsAny reports whether any Unicode code points in chars are within s.
```

You can read the documentation from a terminal running the command:

```sh
go doc strings.IndexAny # or any go function or package you want
```